# Is it possible to remove blue lines in Mega Man 10 in widescreen mode on PS3?

Tags: ps3, mega-man-10

Is it possible to remove the blue lines at the left and right of the game viewport on my widescreen plasma TV? I'm afraid the blue lines might cause image burn.

**edit**

Yes, I have a widescreen TV. I'm playing on the PS3.

Comment: what blue lines? can you include a screenshot?

Comment: I take it you have a widescreen TV, and the game does not make use of widescreen ratios?

Comment: I modified the question, with the assumption that you have a widescreen TV. Which platform is this on?

Comment: Are you playing Megaman X on SNES, or are you playing one of those megaman collection games for other platforms like gamecube?